# how to get the html5 time input to display 00:00 instead of 12:00 in the input field?

Tags: javascript, css, html, time

the original input field display is hh:mm am/pm, I got some CSS codes that turned the display into hh:mm:ss, but it won't display 00:--:-- even if the input value is 00:--:--, instead it displays 12:--:--. is there a way to fix this? perhaps by CSS or JS?

edit: is there another way to have a similar styled input field that takes input in the form of hh:mm:ss into "hh:mm:ss"?

Comment: I think that this has something to do with AM/PM and 24h time format..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have [**tried so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: give more details, right now it is not clear what is the desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using -

```
<input type="time" name="time" />
```

Then Chrome may not display it in 24 hour format but other browsers may.